# JQuery: How to style this on hover and remove others? [JSFiddle inside]

Tags: jquery, hover

Here is the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fmdsu9Lo/

I want to add a hover function so that hovering over the menu will apply the .current styling on that menu tab while removing it from the currently-opened tab.  How can this be done?

```
    $( function() {

        $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).click( function() {

            var tabID = $( this ).attr( 'data-tab' );

            $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).removeClass( 'current' );
            $( '.tab-content' ).removeClass( 'current' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'current' );
            $( "#"+tabID ).addClass( 'current' );

        });

    });
```

Comment: Use `.hover()` instead of `.click()` ??

Comment: And then how would you open the menu?

Comment: What menu? Have a look [example](https://jsfiddle.net/02ws5dct/) Can you specify what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$('ul.cola-tabs').on('click','li',function() {
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
  $("#"+$(this).data('tab')).addClass('current');
}).on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
  $('ul.cola-tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
})
```

```js
$('ul.cola-tabs').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
 $( '.tab-content' ).removeClass( 'current' );
 $( "#"+$(this).data('tab') ).addClass( 'current' );
}).on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
 $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).removeClass( 'current' );
  $( this ).addClass( 'current' );
})
```

```css
ul.cola-tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
 }

 ul.cola-tabs li {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 ul.cola-tabs li:first-child {
  margin: 0;
 }
 
 ul.cola-tabs li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 ul.cola-tabs li.current {
  background: red;
 }
 
 .tab-content {
  display: none;
 }

 .tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cola-tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Apples</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Oranges</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Grapes</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"> apples </div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"> oranges </div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"> grapes </div>
```

Comment: I don't want the content to change on hover, I only want the styling of the menu itself to change on hover. I still want the content to change on click.

Comment: Is this what you asked?